# Pine Script Check for Condition

Tags: pine-script

I have a script that colours the background based on a simple trend. I want to add an alert after the downtrend is finished but I'm not sure how to code it

```
startDown = (fiveEMA < fiveEMA[1] and fiveEMA[1]<fiveEMA[2]and fiveEMA[2]<fiveEMA[3])
startUp = (fiveEMA > fiveEMA[1] and fiveEMA[1]>fiveEMA[2] and fiveEMA[2]>fiveEMA[3])

bgcolor(color=startUp ? color.green : startDown ? color.gray : na)
```

I've tried barssince but could not get the syntax correct

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
if barssince(startDown) == 1
     alert("Start of uptrend", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

if barssince(startUp) == 1
     alert("Start of downtrend", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

**Or** like this?

```
if barssince(startDown) == 1
     alert("End of downtrend", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

if barssince(startUp) == 1
     alert("End of uptrend", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```